# Link to app in the Store with UWP

Tags: hyperlink, uwp

As I understand the following doesn't work anymore for UWP:

```
ms-windows-store:reviewapp?appid=[app ID]
```

Has anyone got the latest on how to do this?

Comment: No, still can be used in UWP app, and your code is for launching the write a review experience for a app, if you want to link to app, use for example  `ms-windows-store://pdp/?ProductId=9WZDNCRFHVJL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to the MSDN in this link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt228343.aspx

Especially for UWP, I suggest to use "ms-windows-store://**review**/?ProductId=".
The product id is much more useful than PFN.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code to accomplish the task in UWP.

```
var uriRate = new Uri(@"ms-windows-store:REVIEW?PFN=" + Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.Id.FamilyName);
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uriRate);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of good articles on this topic on the official documentation site: [Link to your app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/publish/link-to-your-app) and [Launching the store app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-store-app)

In short, you can still use the store protocol, but you don't use `appId` you need to use `productId` which you can get from the developer dashboard.

```
ms-windows-store://review/?ProductId=[pid]
```